# Adding droppable and ajax behavior to outputPanel JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a board where I can drop object and want to do it dynamically.

What I want to have is something like this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="ASlot1" styleClass="slot">  
    <p:droppable tolerance="fit" activeStyleClass="slotActive" scope="PC1" datasource="availableComputers">  
        <p:ajax listener="#{sampleUI.onDrop}" update="selectedComputers" />  
    </p:droppable>  
</p:outputPanel>
```

Backing Bean:

```
HtmlPanelGroup panel;
OutputPanel table [][] = new OutputPanel[x][y];
Panel p = new Panel();

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        table[i][j] = new OutputPanel();
        table[i][j].setId(tableConcat+i+j);
        table[i][j].setStyle(" background:#444444; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; boarder-style: solid;");
        grid.getChildren().add(table[i][j]);
    }
}

panel.getChildren().add(grid);

p.setId("pnel");
panel.getChildren().add(p);

RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.update("panelForm");
```

JSF Page:

```
<h:form id="panelForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="panelIt" binding="#{pane.panel}"/>
</h:form>
```

What will I add to my backing bean?

EDIT:

So I added this

```
 Droppable d = new Droppable();

 d.setScope("PCName");
 d.setDatasource("availableComputers");
 d.setActiveStyleClass("slotActive");
 d.setOnDrop("handleDrop");
 d.setTolerance("fit");
```

Then put each one in the dynamically created outputpanel

```
d.getChildren().add(table[i][j]);
```

It does not seem to work.

Comment: So you should implement the `onDrop` method. Did you see that [showcase example?](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/droppableBarca.jsf)

Comment: I can may that method, i just want to add a droppable and ajax behavior to that outputPanel via backing beans

Answer (score 0):

First you need to drag sth. to be able to drop it so I am going to follow the [showcase example:](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/droppableBarca.jsf)

```
<p:panel header="Squad">  
            <p:dataGrid id="availablePlayers" value="#{barcelona.players}" var="player" columns="4">  
                <p:column>  
                    <p:graphicImage id="player" value="/images/barca/#{player.photo}" styleClass="playerImage"/>  

                    <p:draggable for="player" revert="true" scope="#{player.position}" stack=".playerImage"/>  
                </p:column>  
            </p:dataGrid>  
        </p:panel>
```

Here it has a `dataGrid` that is full with player modal class(pojo) and `p:draggable` makes those images draggable. As you implemented `p:droppable` and `p:ajax` inside of it enables to call a backing bean method with taking dropped player id by:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{barcelona.onDrop}" update="selectedPlayers growl" />
```

All you need to implement `onDrop` method:

```
public void onDrop(DragDropEvent event) {  
    Player player = (Player) event.getData();  
    selectedPlayers.add(player);  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(player.getName() + " added", "Position:" + event.getDropId()));  
}
```

Here it gets the specific player that we have dropped and adds a `FacesMessage` which will be shown on the growl. You can do whatever you want with that specific player going to DB and save it or etc.

If you want to gain droppable skill for multiple outputpanels you should inform the client side about that via:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("x", x);
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("y", y);
```

Then use sth. similar to below js function call it when you are constructing outputpanels:

```
function gainDroppable() {
    var x = '#{sampleUI.x}';
    var y = '#{sampleUI.x}';
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        $(element) = $(document.getElementById('table:'+x+'outputPanel'+'y');
        element.append('<p:droppable tolerance=&quot;fit&quot; activeStyleClass=&quot;slotActive&quot; scope=&quot;PC1&quot; datasource=&quot;availableComputers&quot;>  
        <p:ajax listener=&quot;#{sampleUI.onDrop}&quot; update=&quot;selectedComputers&quot; />  
    </p:droppable> ');
        }
    }
}
```

You should alter a few things about upper function surely, because of I don't know what is your exact client code, the client ID generation should be different for `document.getElementById`.

But this is the way you should follow. Actually generating outputpanels on server side can be harmful and occur lot's of issues in the future so I suggest get rid of that client side codes on Java and try to implement similar via javascript.

Comment: Uhm, i think that's not it. I want to add droppable and ajax behavior via backing bean. I added outputPanels via backing bean `OutputPanel table [][] = new OutputPanel[x][y];` now I want to do the same as droppable and ajax. I generate the number of droppable areas in the backing bean