# Adding JSF tags/components via jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Here is what I did:

```
var a = $(document.getElementById("panelForm:tableId01"));
$("<p:outputLabel value='Testing'/>").appendTo(a);
```

It does not show the label but if I did this, for example, it works:

```
$("<font color='red'>Red</font>").appendTo(a);
```

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have completely missed the point of JSF and the context of JavaScript.

JSF is basically a HTML code generator. To see it yourself, create a (simple and working) JSF page and open it in your favourite webbrowser. Rightclick and choose *View Source*. What do you see? Yes, it's one and all HTML code! If JSF has done its job right, you should not see any JSF tags, for the very simple reason that the webbrowser do not understand them. It understands only HTML.

JavaScript is a client side language which runs in webbrowser and not in webserver. As evidence, when you run webserver and webbrowser at physically different machines and you invoke JavaScript `onclick="alert('peek-a-boo')"`, then you see it in webbrowser, not in webserver. JavaScript can see the HTML DOM tree (anything which is available via `document` object, such as `document.getElementById("someId")`). JavaScript can not see original server side source code who's responsible for generating that HTML, let alone execute it. For jQuery it is not different for the simple reason that it's a JavaScript based library.

You need to solve your concrete functional requirement differently. If you want to dynamically add JSF components, then you should be doing it via JSF itself, not via JavaScript. Here's an answer showing one of the many ways: [How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/how-to-dynamically-add-jsf-components). If you however insist in using jQuery for this, then you should be specifying the JSF component's HTML output yourself, but you're basically still completely missing the point of JSF. Carefully read the below link then.

#### See also:

- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved from CSS, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I did that method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096595/adding-droppable-and-ajax-behavior-to-outputpanel-jsf but does not seem to work

Comment: You're welcome. That is a different problem than stated in the current question.

Comment: Yes and I used a user's(Ömer Faruk Almalı) approach that is this question

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `"$('<p:outputLabel value='Testing'/>')"`. Because it is PrimeFaces tag lib. It will generate html tag (Ex: `'<label class="my-class ui-outputlabel ui-widget" id="j_idt19:j_idt22">Testing</label>'`) when page rendered. So you should use jquery for html tag. For example like below:

```
<p:outputLabel value='Testing' styleClass='my-class'/>"

var a = $(document.getElementById("panelForm:tableId01"));
$("label.my-class").appendTo(a);
```

Comment: so how will I be able to get those html tags? I used the attr() method to set a value for 'class' but it does not work

Comment: because <p:outputLabel> tag will generate to html <label> tag automatic. You can use FireBug (if you use Firefox browser) to know it's html tag that PrimeFaces generated.

Comment: You can do like below: <p:outputLabel id='myLabel' value='Testing' styleClass='my-class'/>"

var a = $(document.getElementById("panelForm:tableId01"));
$("label[id*=myLabel]").appendTo(a);

Comment: I think that can not append PrimeFaces tag using Javascript. You should do it according to other ways. Because JavaScript do not understand PrimeFaces tag. You just can do it via html tag